# How to change a MenuItem icon from normal java class in Android?

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

In my project, I have a class inherited from CountDownTimer, and I want to change a certain MenuItem Icon in the onFinish() method. But the code didn't work.

```
@Override
public void onFinish() {
    Menu menu = newMenuInstance(context);
    MenuInflater menuInflater = new MenuInflater(context);
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.menu_work).setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_action_tick);
}

protected Menu newMenuInstance(Context context) {
    try {
        Class<?> menuBuilderClass = Class.forName("com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder");

        Constructor<?> constructor = menuBuilderClass.getDeclaredConstructor(Context.class);

        return (Menu) constructor.newInstance(context);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: add invalidateOptionsMenu(); in onFinish() method after setting the new icon

Comment: Hi Yasir, my CountDownTimer class is not a inner class of an activity or fragment, is there a way to use the method invalidateOptionsMenu() outside the activity?

Comment: You can only call this function, with that particular activity referecnce

Comment: ((MainActivity)context).invalidateOptionsMenu();                                         I add this line to the code and it works.

Comment: Just now, you didn't write the answer, just commented the question. Now I accept your answer, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add invalidateOptionsMenu(); in onFinish() method after setting the new icon.

If you're not calling this from activity, Please keep in mind that You can only call this function, with that particular activity reference.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are changing the menu items apart from `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method, you have to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to refresh the menu items.